# Can we edit the endpoints.py and add new functions to it in airflow?

Tags: python, api, flask, airflow

I have new functions and I want to call them through api/experimental/route_name

I have the below function and want to integrate it with the airflow so that whenever I call the api/experimental/api_userDetail the details show up.

I have included the function in the file [endpoints.py] . For some reason, it is not showing up in the server and says 404 error. Would be great if I get some method to do so.

````
def returnFromVariable(key_name):
    return Variable.get(key_name,deserialize_json=True)

@api_experimental.route('/api_userDetail',methods=['GET'])
def userDetailApi():
    get_element_config_name="user_credential"
    return jsonify(returnFromVariable(get_element_config_name))```

The output is the data returned.
````

Comment: How do you register your package? If you use Blueprint, you have to register your package first. Or show your structure.

Comment: I simply opened the file and used api_experimental decorator which was actually handled by Blueprint. can you tell me how to register the package?

Comment: Should call your package in your main file and using register_blueprint to register your package. I don't see how you structure your app so I can't guess too much.

Comment: thanks for help actually I have the basic structure of airflow. I actually added the new functions inside the site_package/airflow/www/api/experimental/endpoint.py file. This file is already provided when you download airflow. I hope this clears some thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the stuff worked. I had two versions of airflow running one on python2 and another on python3 so I had to made changes in python3 and that worked for me. The above stuff which I wrote worked. To add the new functionalities simply go to www/api/experimental and then add the api to the file and restart the webserver it will work.